# After I exit from the remote server(CentOS-7), the `python3 manage.py runserver` will not work

Tags: python, django

I use the `python3 manage.py runserver` run the APIs of my Django-Rest-Framework project in my remote server(CentOS-7).

But after I exit from the remote server(CentOS-7), the APIs will not service.

If I login again to the remote server, APIs still not work, but I list the `runserver` command, it is there.

```
[root@www ~]# ps aux | grep runserver
lll      26439  0.0  0.5 275884 41704 ?        S    07:29   0:00 python3 manage.py runserver
lll      26443  3.1  1.0 380044 83264 ?        S    07:29  10:22 /home/lll/repo/Qit/venv_dist/bin/python3 manage.py runserver
root     32575  0.0  0.0 112680   972 pts/1    S+   12:56   0:00 grep --color=auto runserver
```

My question is, when I login the remote server to runserver the django, the APIs works, but I logout the remote server, the APIs can not access now.

---

My settings of `wsgi.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Qn.settings")

import django

print("django.setup()")
django.setup()

from socketio import Middleware
from qn_admin_website_chat.views import sio

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)

import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

Some friends said can use `eventlet.wsgi.server` as distribute server, so I use this way to deployment my project.

Comment: Well that is logical: runserver listens to incoming request on a port. What is your question?

Comment: My question is, when I login the remote server to runserver the django, the APIs works, but I logout the remote server, the APIs can not access now.

Comment: Well you can start the server for instance with `screen` and detach the process, but usually people use a deploy system that calls the script.

Comment: see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124897/how-do-i-detach-a-screen-session-from-a-terminal

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I use the eventlet.wsgi.server as the server, I  hear of can use this as the distribution server.

Answer (score 0):

Better use uWSGI in systemd service.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/app.service
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/blabla/virtualenv/bin/uwsgi --ini /path/to/config.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

% sudo systemctl enable --now app.service
```

Comment: when I exit the ssh, the APIs will not service. and how to solve this problem bro?